# How to compare datatime in python?

Tags: python-2.7, python-datetime

Goal:I need to find the difference between the start_time and current_time and see if its greater then an hour .

start_time = 2016-08-15 23:52:51
current_time = 2016-08-17 13:42:12

How do that in python ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Datetime and timedelta

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> delta = datetime(2016,8,15,23,52,51) - datetime(2016,8,17,13,42,12)
>>> delta
datetime.timedelta(-2, 36639)
>>> delta.seconds
36639
```